# Installing protobuf package for cmake with Protobuf_LIBRARIES and Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: python, windows, cmake, pip

I am trying to install the package `super-gradients=2.0.0` in python with the command
`pip3 install super-gradients=2.0.0`

This fails due to the missing module/package Protobuf.
It tries to build a wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml).

*Error:*

**CMake Error at F:/Visual Studio 2022 Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):**
**Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)**

All the other posts on this website did not help either.

I tried to install it via these instructions:
**https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/**

I also saw some tips to include the parameters Protobuf_LIBRARIES and Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR in the CMakeLists.txt, problem is that i have 3 different text files of that kind located in different modules, no idea which one's correct. Where is the root CMakeLists.txt located or does that even exist?

For other OS than Windows it seems to be pretty easy but this is holding me back since 2 days already

Comment: It's always best to include your complete error message as text NOT links/images and should begin at the word *Traceback*. The error message you posted may not give us the full picture.